# more than one contact form block?

Tags: emails

I have this module enabled

http://drupal.org/project/contact_form_blocks

but I only have one contact form block, which is set to global.  How would I make another contact form block?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform), to create many flexible forms. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... is the module for making surveys in Drupal. After a submission, users may be sent an e-mail "receipt" as well as sending a notification to administrators. Results can be exported into Excel or other spreadsheet applications. Webform also provides some basic statistical review and has and extensive API for expanding its features.